# Left control key not working in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I'm having an issue. I'm trying to install Gentoo in virtualbox. I can't use  `nano` because when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>, I see, I have written `x` letter. Something's wrong with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key in virtualbox. I've seen similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/102834/problem-with-ctrl-key-in-virtual-box), but the answer doesn't work to me. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the right Ctrl key or the left - I think the right one is automatically designated as the 'host' key

Comment: @Wilf Left ctrl key. I know about 'host' key.

Comment: VirtualBox is rather buggy, but left+control has always worked for me. As one example of VB's buggyness, its host-only network adapter randomly just stops working in Windows.  Closer to the OP, my right alt+letter combinations to get non-English accents like ñ sometimes, but not always, do not work in other Windows apps while I’m running VirtualBox.

Comment: Have you tried installing the VirtualBox addons? They always seem to solve mouse and keyboard related issues like these for me.

Comment: Already answered on SuperUser: [Ctrl key doesn't work in Virtual Box, Linux host](http://superuser.com/questions/102834/problem-with-ctrl-key-in-virtual-box)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a LOT of research I found that it was a misconfiguration in my Gnome desktop settings of my host machine.  I had a feature turned on which intercepted my control keys (left and right) and displayed a sort of animated bulls-eye on the cursor when either is pressed.  The trouble with that accessibility feature is that it doesn't pass the control key on to any programs.

```
The solution was to turn it off.  To do so from Linux Mint 13 Maya (MATE) do the following:
1 - Click on the Menu button on the lower left corner of the screen.
2 - Click on Preferences
3 - Click on Assistive Technologies
4 - Click on Mouse Accessibility
5 - Click on the General tab
6 - Under Locate Pointer, uncheck the box that says "Show position of pointer when the Control key is pressed".
```

I'm attaching a screen shot with all those menus displayed, and the relevant check box circled in red.
[image]

Comment: This worked for my Mint MATE 18.1 too